# Difference between Java SE & Java EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

What is the difference between Java SE & Java EE?

Comment: whwr would i download it from? i mean j2ee.. i have j2se installedI want j2ee

Comment: "What's wrong with Google?" Nothing, except SO is the site we want Google to point you to for programming questions.

Comment: You can download **implementations** of Java SE and Java EE from a wide variety of places.  My answer below gives you two places as a starting point, but really there are by now probably over a dozen Java EE implementations including (but not limited to) JBoss, Geronimo, Glassfish, WebSphere, WebLogic BEA, JoNaS, etc.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Java SE (standard edition) is just the normal specification of Java. Java EE (enterprise edition) is Java with all sorts of add-ons for enterpris-y things like:

- Enterprise JavaBeans;
- Java Persistence API;
- Servlets;
- Java Server Pages.

(not an exhaustive list, more detail available on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_EE)). You generally get Java SE when you download the SDK (for development) or JRE (for running Java applications).

On the other hand, you generally get all the Java EE goodies when you start using IBM Websphere Application Server, or JBoss, or another enterprise-class application server.

You can download the Oracle Java EE 6 SDK [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/overview/index.html). The JSR for Java EE 6 is [here](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=316).

Comment: How is this answer marked up so much when it's wrong in almost every detail?

Comment: Perhaps your opinion is incorrect :-)

Comment: J2EE (now called JEE) is more than this...

Comment: @StephenC: JavaBeans has nothing to do with JavaEE.  I think he meant *Enterprise* JavaBeans (which share nothing with JavaBeans but a confusing portion of the name).  In his answer he doesn't actually manage to get straight that Javas SE and EE are *specifications*, not implementations. And on and on and on.

Answer (score 19):

*Java SE* (full name: *Java Platform, Standard Edition*, old names too many to enumerate) is a specification of a programming platform that consists of:

1. The Java programming language itself.
2. A virtual machine that the Java compiler targets.
3. A set of standard libraries.
4. A set of standard utilities related to the above.

Confusingly it's also the default name of a specific implementation of the Java SE specification (the proper name being various combinations of the Java SE name with "JDK" or "JRE" attached).  You can find out more about *Java SE* (and most especially the Oracle JDK/JRE implementation) [on Oracle's page for it](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/index-jsp-136246.html) (latest stable version).

*Java EE* (full name: *Java Platform, Enterprise Edition*, old names, as above, too many to enumerate) is a specification of **another** programming platform—a framework, really—that is built up on top of the *Java SE* platform.  This platform is intended to add functionality for modern business applications like web applications, n-tier architectures, etc.  There are a myriad of implementations of this specification out there—both open source and proprietary—including Oracle's *Glassfish*/Java EE SDK, IBM's *Websphere*, Apache's *Geronimo*, etc.  You can find more information about Java EE (and the *Glassfish*/Java EE SDK implementation of it) again [on Oracle's page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/overview/index.html).

Answer (score 6):

You can just know this for short:
Java SE is for desktop applications and it is the core of Java.
Java EE is for web applications which include JSP & Servlet, EJB, Webservice and they are kinda extensions. You can use them when install a Servlet container (Tomcat) or a JPA provider (Oracle Toplink, Hibernate) or an entire Web application which includes servlet container, JPA provider such as JBoss, GlassFish.

Comment: +1 for short and simple answer j2se for desktop and j2ee for web :)

Answer (score -2):

Best way to understand is to read the Java EE tutorials:

- for Java EE 5: [here](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/)
- for Java EE 6: [here](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/)